# How to set object count to zero(or some value) in NSCountedSet?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsset, nsmutableset, nscountedset

I have following `NSCountedSet`

```
<NSCountedSet: 0x53dfc0> (item1 [2000], item2 [9000], item3 [200], item4  [3000])
```

Now i want to remove `item1` object from my set.
one solution is

```
while([mySet countForObject:item1])
 [mySet removeObject:item1];
```

Output:

```
<NSCountedSet: 0x53dfc0> (item2 [9000], item3 [200], item4  [3000])
```

or i want to remove only 1000 `item1` object from my set.

```
    NSUInteger count = [mySet countForObject:item1];
    while(count)
    {
     [mySet removeObject:item1];
     --count;
    }
```

Output:

```
<NSCountedSet: 0x53dfc0> (item1 [1000], item2 [9000], item3 [200], item4  [3000])
```

is there any better solution for this ?

Comment: if you know the object "item1", you can call directly "removeObject" without having  the loop over mySet.

Comment: @WhiteTiger [removeObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) decrements the count associated with NSCountedSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter with a predicate

```
[mySet filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self != %@", item1]];
```

Comment: is there any way to reduce count of object?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make your own object which can use an NSMutableSet behind the scenes but give you the added behaviour you want...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you understand the problem, so I get these results:

```
<NSCountedSet: 0x6d9ee40> (two [1], three [1], one [1], four [1])

[mySet removeObject:@"one"];

<NSCountedSet: 0x6d9ee40> (two [1], three [1], four [1])
```

Comment: Stick `[mySet addObject:@"one"];` before your `removeObject:` to see this does not work...

Comment: @WhiteTiger your set contain only one [1](count is 1), i have item1 [2000] (count is 2000).

Comment: i hadn't realized  you could have the possibility of having duplicate items

Comment: @WhiteTiger: Such is the purpose of a counted set: it tells you how many of each item is in it. Other kinds of sets do not allow duplicates; every item is either in a non-counted set or not.

Answer (score 0):

NSCountedSet does not offer methods to modify the count of a certain object by a certain amount (a pity really).

If speed is not an issue you can used the methods you described above.  However if you need something else: subclassing NSMutableSet to provide this "counting" functionality is probably your best option.